# How to create shadows and highlights on a subject during photo manipulation in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, composition, image-manipulation, shadows, highlights

What is the best method to **create shadows (darken)** and **highlights (brighten)** on a subject to match the lighting of new background image during photo manipulation in Photoshop?

Comment: Can you add a sample image where the subject does not match the background?

Comment: Match the lighting how?  The color, direction, softness?  If the foreground and background are not lit the same, you probably would use Photoshop > Filter > Render > Lighting Effects to try to match the direction and hardness/softness of the light, as well as the color.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called Dodging (to lighten) and Burning (to darken) in Photograph, techniques that come all the way from shooting and developing film.

Photoshop have specific tools for doing this, but the way I like to do it is non-destructively - try using this as a guide:

http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/dodge-burn/